# Extract the number of bing search results

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to use web scraping using `rvest` to extract the number of bing search results.

I use the following function:

```
BingResults <- function(x) {
    stringr::str_glue('https://www.bing.com/search?q="{x}"') %>% 
        rvest::session() %>% 
        rvest::html_elements(xpath = '//*[@id="b_tween_searchResults"]/span') %>% 
        rvest::html_text() %>% 
        stringr::str_remove_all("Ungefähr|Ergebnisse|results|About| |\\.") %>% 
        as.integer() %>% 
        "/"(1000) %>% 
         as.integer()
}
```

However, this works for some words but does not work for some others

```
BingResults(x = "Diversity")
# 19700
BingResults(x = "Aktie")
# integer(0)
```

Is there a reason for the failure in the second example? How to make the function works for all possible search terms.

Comment: are you wanting the number, or more specifically, are you wanting the number in thousands, as an integer?

Comment: The problem is in the results of `html_nodes` for some words like `"Aktie"`, which gives `{xml_nodeset (0)}`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

bing_results <- function(search_term) {
  str_c("https://www.bing.com/search?q=", search_term) %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_element(".sb_count , .sb_bp") %>%
    html_text2() %>%
    str_remove_all("[^0-9]") %>%
    as.numeric()
}

bing_results("Aktie")

[1] 7390000
```

Comment: Thanks. but this does not work for me. `bing_results(search_term = "Aktie")` gives 1.

Answer (score 1):

The code you're looking for is:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, rvest)

BingResults <- function(x) {
    str_glue('https://www.bing.com/search?q="{x}"') %>% 
      read_html %>%
      html_nodes('.sb_count') %>%
      html_text %>%
      parse_number %>%
      {. / 1000} %>%
      as.integer
}
```

I'm not able to reproduce your problem, as for me, both `BingResults(x = "Diversity")` and `BingResults(x = "Aktie")` return `NA`. This is because you get results like "19,700,000" from the `stringr::str_remove_all("Ungefähr|Ergebnisse|results|About| |\\.") %>%` line, which, when turned into integers, become `NA`s, because of the commas. As such, the smallest change you could make to make this code work is to add a comma to the regex for the `str_remove_all()` line, and it ought to work.

Comment: The problem for me is not how to handle the results of `html_text` but that the `html_nodes` function gives `{xml_nodeset (0)}` for `"Aktie"` and other words.

Comment: it doesn't give the same for me...could you potentially post the HTML for it into your question?

Comment: @AhmedEl-Gabbas please answer above

Comment: I just found that the search results of "Aktie" do not show the number of results also on the browser. I am searching for this word from Germany, and this word means "share" or "stock". For this search term, Bing shows some results from `Explore stocks on MSN Money` without showing the number of search results (probably because I am based in Germany). This is probably the reason for the discrepancy in the results between us.

Comment: @AhmedEl-Gabbas do you still get a "About x Results" thing in the page